# Import Github is not showing all my public repositories

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

It is only showing 7 of the 24 public repositories that I have.

You'll also notice that the html in the project description is not escaped properly, possible injection issue?

My github account is: https://github.com/krisleech

[image: screen grab]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks! Indeed, an encoding issue. Try it again?