# In Careers: GitHub Repositories Limited to 30?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, github

This appears to be a similar issue to:
[Import Github is not showing all my public repositories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115103/import-github-is-not-showing-all-my-public-repositories)

It appears this is now limited to 30 repositories when importing from GitHub.  Could this be due to pagination?  I have more than 30 projects I've written that I'd like to show on my account.

My GitHub address is www.github.com/huntergdavis

Thanks!

Comment: On the face of it this doesn't seem related at all, did you see the answer to the other question?

Comment: Why does this have Off-Topic votes?

Comment: @Kobobby Perhaps because at first glance it looks like a question about GitHub, not SO Careers.

Comment: Well it is definitely a problem with SO Careers, not GitHub.  It is also quite similar to the linked question (7 repositories showing out of 24 in that case, 30 out of 80 in my case).  I believe it to be caused by GitHub's pagination used in it's API, which limits the default API results to 30.  If this is the case SO Careers is only getting the first page of results, and should either append "?per_page=100" to their query or loop over each page with "?page=2" etc.  This shouldn't be a large fix and is certainly not off-topic.

Comment: What happened to the days of showing your top five on the CV and then linking to the full repo hunt listings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix to Careers has now been deployed to retrieve all your Github Projects.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to list all repos, pass the page number parameter along with the access token as ?accessToken=%@&page=2. You would get all the repos on page no. 2.